# Google maps API to extract company details

Tags: python, r, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to extract the details displayed when you search for a company name on google maps. As shown in the image below:

[image: Google maps search results]

I tired the `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=` this gives only the formatted_address. But I need to get the website and contact details from the results. Can someone help me what is the possible API to use for this? Also it would be nice if the code is in R or python.

Comment: What do you have as input ? The adresses ? The company name ?

Comment: For R you could try the [googleway package](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway).

Answer (score 0):

The URL you mentioned is a [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start), for company details you should use **places** method from [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details).

Answer (score 0):

As @Procrastinatus points out you can use my googleway package to do this in R using the `google_places()` function. And you need a valid Google API key .

Note that what you see on Google Maps isn't always what is returned by the Places API.

```
library(googleway)

## your valid api key
# api_key <- read.dcf("~/Documents/.googleAPI", fields = "GOOGLE_API_KEY")

search_res <- google_places(search_string = "Olympus Avenue, Warwick, UK", 
                            key = api_key)

search_res$results$name
# [1] "Holiday Inn Leamington Spa - Warwick"


search_res <- google_places(search_string = "Assured Property Group, UK", 
                            key = api_key)
search_res$results$name
# [1] "Assured Property"

search_res$results$formatted_address
# [1] "77 Market St, Droylsden, Manchester M43 6DD, United Kingdom"

geo <- google_geocode(address = "Assured Property Group, Olympus Avenue, Warwick, UK", 
                      key = api_key)

search_res <- google_places(location = c(geo$results$geometry$location$lat, 
                                         geo$results$geometry$location$lng),
                            radius = 1000,
                            key = api_key)

search_res$results$name
# [1] "Holiday Inn Leamington Spa - Warwick" "McDonald's"                          
# [3] "Pure Offices Leamington Spa"          "Canute Group"                        
# [5] "Local Taxis"                          "Timpson Locksmith's & Safe Engineers"
# [7] "mplcontact"                           "Roast Coffee Weight Loss"            
# [9] "We Buy Your Tyres"                    "Diamond Taxis"                       
# [11] "NS Line Cars"                         "Costa Coffee Drive Thru"
```